# Can't load admob ads in view programmatically in my iphone game app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, admob

I have an iPhone game app in objective c  which uses a private class to load every view programmatically. (without using nib files) I am trying to place an admob ads in the view but it seems I can't have it to work. I tried to place my admob ads view in the init method but still it doesn't load the view.

Here are some codes of how I initialize the data to load the view:

```
-(id)init
{
    if( (self=[super init]))
    {
        played_ = NO;

        KWSprite* background = [KWSprite spriteWithFile:@"title_background.png"];
        background.position = ccp(winSize_.width/2, winSize_.height/2);

        KWSprite* logo = [KWSprite spriteWithFile:@"logo.png"];
        logo.position = ccp(winSize_.width/2, 260);    

        CCMenuItemImage* start = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"start.png" selectedImage:@"start_selected.png" target:self selector:@selector(pressStartButton:)]
        CCMenuItemImage* credit  = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"credit.png" selectedImage:@"credit_selected.png" target:self selector:@selector(pressCreditButton:)];
        CCMenuItemImage* iADButton  = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"noAdsD.png" selectedImage:@"noAdsD@2x.png" target:self selector:@selector(pressiAdButton:)];

        CCMenuItemImage* howto = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"howto.png" selectedImage:@"howto_selected.png" target:self selector:@selector(pressHowtoButton:)];

        CCMenu* menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:howto, start, credit, iADButton, nil];
        [menu alignItemsHorizontally];
        menu.position = ccp(winSize_.width/2, 40); 
        [self addChild:background];
        [self addChild:logo];
        [self addChild:menu];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using Cocos2D here. If you're using a version afte v0.99.5b3, I'd recommend putting your AdMob code within the RootViewController class. It would be better for OpenGL performance since you're not combining your UIKit views with your OpenGL views.

On a high level, you have to add a GADBannerView to your RootViewController's view, then reduce the size of the Cocos2D OpenGL view to make sure the ad shows. What this might look like is below (this code assumes the ad is positioned at the top):

```
- (void)showBanner {
  // Frame of the main RootViewController which we call the root view.
  CGRect rootViewFrame = self.view.frame;
  // Frame of the main RootViewController view that holds the Cocos2D view.
  CGRect glViewFrame = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView].frame;
  // Frame of the GADBannerView
  CGRect bannerViewFrame = bannerView_.frame;
  CGRect frame = bannerViewFrame;
  // The updated x and y coordinates for the origin of the banner.
  CGFloat yLocation = 0.0;
  CGFloat xLocation = 0.0;


  // Move the root view underneath the ad banner.
  glViewFrame.origin.y = bannerViewFrame.size.height;
  // Center the banner using the value of the origin.
  if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInt)) {
    // The superView has not had its width and height updated yet so use those
    // values for the x and y of the new origin respectively.
    xLocation = (rootViewFrame.size.height -
                    bannerViewFrame.size.width) / 2.0;
  } else {
    xLocation = (rootViewFrame.size.width -
                    bannerViewFrame.size.width) / 2.0;
  }
  frame.origin = CGPointMake(xLocation, yLocation);
  bannerView_.frame = frame;

  if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInt)) {
    // The super view's frame hasn't been updated so use its width
    // as the height.
    glViewFrame.size.height = rootViewFrame.size.width -
                                    bannerViewFrame.size.height;
    glViewFrame.size.width = rootViewFrame.size.height;
  } else {
    glViewFrame.size.height = rootViewFrame.size.height -
                                    bannerViewFrame.size.height;
  }
  [[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView].frame = glViewFrame;

}
```